# R: How to perform a chiquare test on two groups & each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
>head(df)
 alleleA_obs_prob alleleB_obs_prob alleleA_exp_prob alleleB_exp_prob
    0.6923077        0.3076923              0.5              0.5
          NaN              NaN              0.5              0.5
          NaN              NaN              0.5              0.5
    0.6250000        0.3750000              0.5              0.5
    0.6250000        0.3750000              0.5              0.5
          NaN              NaN              0.5              0.5
```

So I have two groups: alleleA and alleleB for which I have observed and expected probabilities.

I have been told to perform a chi-square test on this data, comparing the expected and observed probabilities of the two groups together. I searched through a lot of tutorials but couldn't understand how a chisquare test works on two groups. To be clear, I don't want people to post codes for me and I am NOT asking you to do my homework. I am just unsure because

1. By going through existing chisquare test examples on the web, I couldn't relate how a chisquare test can be performed on my data.
2. I couldn't find any examples where a test is performed between two groups collectively.
3. Couldn't find examples where they perform chisquare test for each row in a dataframe.

I want a chisquare value & a p-value for each row. Everywhere I look, they perform a chisquare test on the entire dataframe.

I just want some help, please share links or share insights, in whichever way you like, on how do I solve this problem. But please do not assume that I want you to write my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is a statistics question, not an R question really. You should try posting it on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com), where you are likely to get a much better answer.

Second, there are two types of chi-square test, one to assess whether a sample is from a given test distribution, and one to test for independence. I assume that you are interested in the first type.

If that is correct, then it looks like you are asking - using the first row of your df as an example - how likely is it, if allele A and allele B are present in equal amounts, that you could get a sample where allele A is present at 69% and allele B is present at 31%? If the likelihood (p) is very low, then we can assert with confidence 1-p that allele A and allele B were not present in equal amounts.

[NB: If this is *not* what you are asking, then I am misunderstanding your question - let me know in a comment and I'll delete the answer.]

In your case it is probably better to skip the vagaries of the `chisq.test(...)` function in R and go directly to the definition of Xi-sq:

> χ<sup>2</sup> = Σ( O<sub>i</sub> - E<sub>i</sub> )<sup>2</sup> / E<sub>i</sub>

Where O<sub>i</sub> and E<sub>i</sub> are the i<sup>th</sup> observed and expected value, respectively. The way you have this set up, in each row there are only 2 observations, for allele A and allele B. So for row 1 we would write:

> χ<sup>2</sup> = (0.692 - 0.5)<sup>2</sup> / 0.5 + (0.307 - 0.5)<sup>2</sup> / 0.5 = 0.148

Since there are only two observations, there is only 1 degree of freedom. Chi-square tests with only 1 df are extremely unreliable, so I *do not recommend this*, but following through for the sake of the example, we can calculate the probability that chi-sq will be this large or larger as follows in R:

```
pchisq(0.148, df=1, lower.tail=F)
# [1] 0.700454
```

This means, assuming that allele A and allele B are present in equal amounts, there is still a 70% chance that you could obtain a sample with allele A present at 69% and allele B present at 31%. So we definately cannot reject the null hypothesis (that allele A and B are present equally).

Running this test for all rows is straightforward:

```
df           <- na.omit(df)          # remove rows with missing values
colnames(df) <- c("A.obs","B.obs","A.exp","B.exp")  # because I'm lazy
df$chisq     <- with(df,(A.obs-A.exp)^2/A.exp + (B.obs-B.exp)^2/B.exp)
df$p.value   <- pchisq(df$chisq,df=1, lower.tail=F)
df
#       A.obs     B.obs A.exp B.exp    chisq   p.value
# 1 0.6923077 0.3076923   0.5   0.5 0.147929 0.7005224
# 4 0.6250000 0.3750000   0.5   0.5 0.062500 0.8025873
# 5 0.6250000 0.3750000   0.5   0.5 0.062500 0.8025873
```

You can in fact use the `chisq.test(...)` function to do this, although in your case I'm not sure it's an improvement:

```
t(apply(df,1,function(x)
        with(chisq.test(x[1:2],p=x[3:4]),c(statistic,p.value=p.value))))
#   X-squared   p.value
# 1  0.147929 0.7005224
# 4  0.062500 0.8025873
# 5  0.062500 0.8025873
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I couldn't find a better one elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they meant is to run the chi-squared test on each of the two groups:

```
chisq.test(df[is.finite(df[, 'alleleA_obs_prob']), c('alleleA_obs_prob', 'alleleA_exp_prob')])
# X-squared = 0.002, df = 2, p-value = 0.999

chisq.test(df[is.finite(df[, 'alleleB_obs_prob']), c('alleleB_obs_prob', 'alleleB_exp_prob')])
# X-squared = 0.0052, df = 2, p-value = 0.9974
```